# Parentheses' height in exercise 18.5 or the TeXbook

Tags: texbook.tex

If I put the answer to exercise 18.5 from Knuth's TeXbook,
i.e.

```
$${n\choose k}\equiv{\lfloor n/p\rfloor\choose
\lfloor k/p\rfloor}{n\bmod p\choose k\bmod p}\pmod p.$$
```

into my pdftex,
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian),
I get parentheses much shorter than the ones on any pdf version of
the book I can find on internet.

Why?

Comment: note if you find any pdf of the book on the internet you should report it to the publisher so steps can be taken to have it removed.

Comment: The texbook source actually has slightly different markup for the question and answer, I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyDeq.png) which looks like the book, I think? what are you seeing?